# Speed up Ruby class to avoid requests to JIRA and Slack API

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, jira-rest-api

My, pure Ruby, class pull out user names from Jira API to convert it into email address and pass these email addresses to another class based on which Slack ID is extracted.

```
module Request
  class GetUser
    def call
      setup_email
    end

    private

    def setup_email
      devops_email = dev_role['actors'].map { |user| "#{user['name']}@example.com" }
      devops_email.each do |email|
        ::Slack::GetUserId.new(email: email).call
      end
    end

    def dev_role
      HTTParty.get('https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/1234/role/1234',
                   basic_auth: { username: 'user', password: 'pass' },
                   headers: { 'content-type' => 'application/json' })
    end
  end
end
```

Because above class will be called every day (AWS Lambda schedule), I want to speed up the class. What should I use to achieve that? Should I use some database (Dynamodb probably?) to save user data (userID and user email) and make a query to check if the data (e.g. user name) has changed?

Or maybe should I change some implementation and leave these requests without saving data to the database?

Comment: What's the slow part – the Jira or Slack calls?

Comment: I think Slack is slowest but not much can be done. I'm using JIRA API to download 20 names (which probably don't change often) and I have to download it on every day request. Don't you think saving them to the database will be a more efficient solution? I mean it could be some request to check if there is some new name and save it to the db instead. WDYT?

Comment: Fetching 20 names once a day doesn't sound like a task that needs optimization.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to fetch all users in a single API call, using the [`search` API](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client#search-for-a-user)? (See the souce [here](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client/blob/40cf30ca99df782de66704616edfac1ef9683622/lib/slack/web/api/mixins/users.search.rb#L15).) Or failing that, you could split this into multiple sub-jobs to query one at a time (either as background tasks, or multi-threaded)... But as Stefan said, for the sake of fetching 20 users once a day I don't think this is worth optimising.

Comment: Is there actually a problem with the speed?
Since this runs on a scheduler it should not matter much if it takes 30sec. or 5min.?

Comment: @Pascal There are certainly good reasons to avoid LONG-running jobs, even on a scheduler. (5 minutes is long!) - For example, you cannot deploy a new version of the application whilst a job is in progress; the job will need to be terminated early. However, I highly doubt these 20 API calls is taking more than a few seconds; certainly nowhere near 5 minutes.

Comment: @TomLord 
I am currenty working on a job that that makes +2k API calls taking a total of 2h. We were able to speed this up to 30s. Data is almost never stale. Would not have added the complexity (generating the cache key required implementation of a new API endpoint) for a 5min job though.